# Split strings in text file everytime a blank line is encountered using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am new to writing batch scripts. I want to split strings from text files and put those strings in variables every time a blank line is encountered in the text file. How can we achieve this via batch script?

My text file looks like:

```
Comparing files E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\order_m.txt and E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\order_m.txt
FC: no differences encountered

Comparing files E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test1.txt and E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test1.txt
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test1.txt
West|CA|Alameda|74|10000|True|Nantes|Poland
West|CA|Los Angeles|26|45000|True|Bern|Plax
West|NV|Washoe|22|77000|True|Paris|Washoe
North|FL|Hernando|65|2000|False|Paris|Asia
North|TA|Plax|70|5500|False|Cowes|Switzerland
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test1.txt
West|CA|Alameda|74|10000|True|Nantes|Poland
West|NV|Los Angeles|26|45000|True|Bern|Plax
West|NV|Washoe|22|77000|True|Paris|Washoe
North|FL|Hernando|65|2000|False|Paris|India
North|TA|Plax|70|5500|False|Cowes|Switzerland
*****

Comparing files E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test2.txt and E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test2.txt
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test2.txt
22,9,H3,4500.0,HP
23,10,H4,4500.0,Delhi
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test2.txt
22,9,H3,4500.0,HP
23,10,H4,4500.0,Agra
*****
```

I want to read above text file and split strings if a blank line is encountered. E.g.

```
var a = Comparing files E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\order_m.txt and E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\order_m.txt
FC: no differences encountered

var b = Comparing files E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test1.txt and E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test1.txt
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_OLDERBUILD\8.0\test1.txt
West|CA|Alameda|74|10000|True|Nantes|Poland
West|CA|Los Angeles|26|45000|True|Bern|Plax
West|NV|Washoe|22|77000|True|Paris|Washoe
North|FL|Hernando|65|2000|False|Paris|Asia
North|TA|Plax|70|5500|False|Cowes|Switzerland
***** E:\UPGRADEAUTOMATION\WINDOWS_INSTALLUPGRADE_AUTOMATION\OUTPUT_TO_COMPARE\OUTPUT_AFTER_UPGRADE\8.0\test1.txt
West|CA|Alameda|74|10000|True|Nantes|Poland
West|NV|Los Angeles|26|45000|True|Bern|Plax
West|NV|Washoe|22|77000|True|Paris|Washoe
North|FL|Hernando|65|2000|False|Paris|India
North|TA|Plax|70|5500|False|Cowes|Switzerland
*****
```

& so on.

Comment: It should be noted that the Windows batch scripting language doesn't easily handle line breaks in variable values.  You might be better off using a different language -- JScript, for example, if you're familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what your end goal is, we might be able to suggest a better way. For example, if you're just wanting to find out the `Comparing files` lines, that could be done. I feel this question is just one step in a much bigger process.

Comment: thanks. actually i want to create a text files with results containing File name and status as pass/Fail. I did it via writing a java code.